# how can I resize images picked from nativescript-imagepicker plugin

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've implemented nativescript image picker plugin  in my Nativescript -Angular code but I'm trying to figure out how to resize image picked from nativescript-imagepicker that can display as Account or Profile picture in circle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `selected` image will be instance of [ImageAsset](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_asset_.imageasset), you may set the [options](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_asset_.imageasset#options) with desired `width` and `height` then call use [fromAsset](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource#fromasset) method on [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_image_source_.imagesource) for resized image.

```
context
    .authorize()
    .then(function() {
        return context.present();
    })
    .then(function(selection) {
        selection.forEach(function(selected) {
            // Set values for width, height, keepAspectRatio (boolean)
            selected.options = {width, height, keepAspectRatio };
            imageSourceModule.fromAsset(selected)
               .then((imageSource) => {
                   // imageSource is resized one
               }); 
        });
    }).catch(function (e) {
        // process error
    });
```

Comment: how can  given image as circle so I can only set height and width ?          selected.options = {
                width: 75,
                height: 75,
                keepAspectRatio: true
            };

Comment: The image holder will always be a square, not circle. You may apply border radius to your layout / view and place the image inside to show it as circle which is easiest.

Comment: thanks Manoj above solution working fine on both android and ios platform